# Ruby: Can I 'require' a file which contains only a class?

Tags: ruby, class, rspec, module

I have a file `/project/lib/invaccessor.rb` with the following content

```
class InvAccessor
  def initialize
    @browser = "browser"
  end
end
```

and a spec file `project/spec/invaccessor_spec.rb` which requires it

```
require_relative '../lib/invaccessor'

describe Invaccessor do
  it {expect(2).to be_even}     
end
```

When I run `rspec spec/invaccessor.rb` I get an `uninitialized constant error` for `Invaccessor`. Do I have to put all file contents in a module in order to access them?

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Can you edit your question to include your Pry session (i.e. everything you typed into Pry and all of the output it gave you)?

Comment: I've posted the original files I was having trouble with and more explicit description of my actions. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your class is `InvAccessor` but you try and reference `Invaccessor`. The name is case sensitive.

Comment: I am just wondering: Is it allowed to completely change a question after it has been answered (and the answer was approved)? Right now, my answer doesn't fit the question anymore. Could you please include the old question, at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Try this inside the directory where your classfile.rb lies:

```
>> require './classfile'
=> true
>> A
=> A
```

You definitely don't have to put a class into a module to require it.